# exit a switch case from within a subroutine

Tags: perl

I wonder how to leave a switch case element from a subroutine like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Switch;

switch ($command) {
    case 'create_vmr' {
        ... do something ...
        callsub($blabla);
        ... do something more ...
    }
    case 'delete_vmr' {
        ... do something ...
        callsub($blabla);
        ... do something more ...
    }
}

... final code ...

exit(0);

sub callsub {
    ... check something ...
    last if $condition;
}
```

My thought was, that 'last' in callsub() will exit the case it was called from, so that the code will proceed after the switch elemeent. But this does not work. 'last' works fine if I call it in the case element directly.

So, how can I leave the switch element from a sub?

edit: And I don't want to use 'goto' please ;)

Comment: FYI, [Switch is buggy and should be avoided.](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5120delta#Switch) It was officially deprecated in 5.12.0. The ["switch" feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements) that replaced it is experimental. Just use `if`/`else`.

Comment: Loose coupling is good principle which saves mental health of programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend not trying to obfuscate your program flow by hiding breaks.

Instead, make the subroutines return a true value if it succeeds, and break from the calling code block.

In this instance, I would recommend using a dispatch table instead of the [deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5120delta#Switch) Switch module.  The following should demonstrate:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %dispatch = (
    create_vmr => sub {
        # ... do something ...
        callsub('foo') or return;
        # ... do something more ...
    },
    delete_vmr => sub {
        # ... do something ...
        callsub('bar') or return;
        # ... do something more ...
    },
);

my $command = 'delete_vmr';

if ( $dispatch{$command} ) {
    $dispatch{$command}();
} else {
    warn "Unrecognized $command";
}

exit(0);

sub callsub {
    # ... check something ...
    return $_[0] eq 'foo';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. The dispatch table is a nice way to go.